# Does Amazon prohibit a family of adults from sharing a single Amazon account?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, terms-of-service, breach-of-contract

In [Amazon's Conditions of Use](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ref_=hp_left_v4_sib&nodeId=GLSBYFE9MGKKQXXM), the section "License and Access" says the following:

> Subject to your compliance with these Conditions of Use and any Service Terms, and your payment of any applicable fees, Amazon or its content providers grant you a limited, non-exclusive, **non-transferable**, non-sublicensable license to access and make personal and non-commercial use of the Amazon Services.

Also, the section "Your Account" says the following:

> You are responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of your account and password and for **restricting access to your account**, and you agree to accept responsibility for all activities that occur under your account or password. Amazon does sell products for children, but it sells them to adults, who can purchase with a credit card or other permitted payment method. If you are under 18, you may use the Amazon Services only with involvement of a parent or guardian. **Parents and guardians may create profiles for teenagers in their Amazon Household.**

However, Amazon Household is limited in how many profiles can be created. For example, you can only have two adult (18+) profiles per household. If a family of more than two adults would like to share a single account instead of getting involved with Amazon Household, would they be in violation of Amazon's terms, whether in the section above or elsewhere?

**Update**

I have just noticed an additional statement of significance in the terms:

> By using the Amazon Services, you agree, on behalf of yourself **and all members of your household and others** who use any Service under your account, to the following conditions.

Might this suggest that the agreement *is* broad enough to apply not only to one individual but *also* to the individual's "household" (and maybe even to "others who use any Service under your account")?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because website terms of use are not laws.

Comment: @bdb484 Is there a different StackExchange that would be better for this topic?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: It doesn't seem there is a better Stack Exchange to ask this question than Law. Furthermore, other ToS-themed questions have been asked without removal. For example, see https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44333/wag-terms-of-service and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7740/is-mcleaks-breaking-the-minecraft-eula. With this in mind, is there anything I could do to improve my question and have it reopened? I'm open to constructive criticism.

Comment: I can't really think of anything. I'd agree that there isn't a better SE page for the question, but that doesn't make it a good fit here. The Internet is lousy with q&a sites, so you'll probably be able to find something else out there.

Comment: @bdb484 I wish I could have avoided the downvotes, especially since other ToS-themed questions have been asked on this site without problem, but if my question doesn't belong, then I guess that's just the way the cookie crumbles. What kind of places are out there that might be good for ToS-themed questions? Is there a particular site or two you have in mind?

Comment: In good news, downvotes are meaningless. I have no ideas or suggestions on better venues for your question, but Google can probably get you there.

Comment: I asked on the Meta Law Stack Exchange how I might modify the question to enter on-topic territory. The answer I got is that the question _is_ on topic due to being about the interpretation of binding clauses, a clear example of contract law. The rulings on such questions can even become precedent in case law. Certainly, if Amazon were to sue over a violation of this contract, no court or arbitrator would say, "Sorry, this dispute does not pertain to law and is thus outside our jurisdiction." Here's the thread: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/how-to-ask-a-better-tos-question

Comment: I had considered that argument, but I still disagree. Parties put all kinds of things into their contracts, but that doesn't necessarily elevate those provisions to legal issues. If Nike offers me $50 million to win the Australian Open wearing its shoes, my footwear and performance in the competition have legal implications, but that doesn't mean "Am I wearing Nikes?" and "Who won the Australian Open?" are questions about the law.

Comment: @bdb484 Yes, the questions "Am I wearing Nikes?" and "Who won the Australian Open?" would not be law questions. However, "Would the Supreme x Nike Dunk Low Pro SB fulfill the shoe criteria for my $50 million agreement with Nike?" and "If I wear Nike shoes during most of the Australian Open but switch to non-Nike shoes during some of the matches, will I still have met the criteria?" _are_ questions about the law. Criminal law isn't the only law. Deciding what qualifies in a terms agreement is also. Otherwise, the terms-of-service and contract-law tags would likely need to be taken off the site.

Comment: I don't agree. In the legal profession, we would call these questions of fact, rather than questions of law. The law doesn't actually take any position on whether your Supreme x Nike Dunk Low Pro SB are Nikes, nor does it take a position on how many adults can be added to an Amazon account. If you ended up litigating either question, the court would just ask what you and the other party meant when you entered into the contract. You and Jeff Bezos would offer your explanations, and the court would go from there.

Comment: Incidentally, I would generally support removing the TOS tag, which is mostly nonsense. There are legal questions about whether TOS can be judicially enforced, etc., but my impression is most questions are like this one, asking what Provision A means in Company X's TOS. Because TOS are not law, I usually vote to delete those questions.

Comment: Yes, reading the contract is the first step in figuring out the parties' intentions. I'm not sure what you think you're correcting here.

Comment: @bdb484 questions about terms of service or other contracts are on topic (unless they are requests for legal advice)

Comment: That's a valid opinion.

Comment: You quoted more than half of the the "Your Account" section but omitted this sentence which appears to be the answer to the question asked: **You may need your own Amazon account to use certain Amazon Services**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Amazon prohibit a family of adults from sharing a single Amazon account?

No, or at least it seems unlikely. As outlined in [my answer & comments](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1386/18505) on Law Meta, a domestic or family-oriented character is palpable in the clause. That weakens the notion that Amazon's intent is to preclude scenarios which are of a personal-domestic nature and short of commercial/sublicensed use.

The language "*You are responsible for [...] restricting access to your account*" seems more permissive than something akin to "*only you are allowed to access your account*". The former language is consistent with the term "*non-exclusive*", which otherwise seems to have no relevance or purpose in the clause.

Users' ability (if any) to enter multiple payment methods with different names (i.e., card holder name) could be an additional indication that the scenario you have in mind is acceptable to Amazon. It is easy for a company to implement a validation for the purpose of identifying significant discrepancies of holder names and/or to have the user confirm that all payment methods refer to one same owner. The latter approach is more conclusive for scenarios where a woman has changed names as a result of getting married or divorced. The fact (?) that Amazon declined to include that simple validation weakens the notion that the company is genuinely interested in sticking to a rule of one-person per account.

Comment: FYI, I added an additional quotation from the terms into the question, which says the one agreeing does so on behalf of anyone who uses the account, not just the one agreeing. Perhaps this further supports your answer.

Comment: I access Amazon services on several devices - phone, Alexa, tablet, PC and TV.  These can certainly be used by any member of my household (we have two adults and a minor child; if I had a live-in employee, parent/sibiling, or unrelated roommate I could simulate the OP's case).   If I attempt to start streaming on a second device, I have to agree to stop the streaming on the first one.  Am I being wronged by this current action?  If Amazon found I had 3+ adults (employee, tenant or sibiling), and terminated our contract upon finding this, would I be wronged?

Comment: @TheEditor "*which says the one agreeing does so on behalf of anyone who uses the account, not just the one agreeing.*" There you go! That conclusively strikes the notion of "only one person per account" and reinforces the points developed in this answer.

Comment: @user662852 Are you asking for information or as a rhetorical device? If the latter, what do you believe the answers are?

Comment: @TheEditor My read is the answer is Amazon's terms are as you quoted in the OP, one adult per user account (which I don't see as different from Dale's answer), but they are limited by technical and commercial considerations in validating this.  This answer is hung up on the absence of one out of several possible technical validations, my comment was a counterexample technical validation.  Prime free shipping and streaming content licensing is expensive, but if the use is not abused, sure: I bet you can cruise under their radar indefinitely as a practical matter.

Comment: @user662852 The central premise is not the company's failure to implement validations, but the language that leaves room for domestic scenarios that involve two or more adults using the service. The company could have been unequivocal instead of stopping at "*restricting access*". The lack of validations only makes it more complicated for Amazon to persuade that its intent was "one adult per account", but that detail is incidental to the terms the OP initially reproduced. The OP's update is conclusive as to effectively allowing "*others [to] use any Service under your account*".

Comment: 1. Whether my wife orders something on my Amazon account, or she asks me to order it and I order it doesn’t make a practical difference. 2. I suspect the clause would be used if I refuse to pay for things that my wife ordered. I should be the only one able to order according to the t&c’s, so they can argue that I’m responsible for all orders on that account.

Comment: @user662852 My question isn't whether you "can cruise under their radar indefinitely as a practical matter," but rather if such violates the terms in the first place. Not only is such not enforced; it doesn't even seem to violate the terms to begin with since we're told, "By using the Amazon Services, you agree, on behalf of yourself and all members of your household and others who use any Service under your account, to the following conditions." Thus, it seems to apply not only to one individual but also to their "household" (and maybe even to "others who use any Service under your account").

Comment: Also, I asked Amazon's customer service, and they also agreed that there's nothing in the terms prohibiting multiple adults from sharing the same Amazon account so long as you're okay with sharing the same credit cards. Just an additional piece of evidence that this answer is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

The original [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ref_=hp_left_v4_sib&nodeId=GLSBYFE9MGKKQXXM) in the question includes quotes from "Your Account" section but not the entire section.  Two sentences were selectively not included in your question which I've bolded.

> **You may need your own Amazon account to use certain Amazon Services**, and you may be required to be logged in to the account and have a valid payment method associated with it. If there is a problem charging your selected payment method, we may charge any other valid payment method associated with your account. Visit Your Payments to manage your payment options. You are responsible for maintaining the confidentiality of your account and password and for restricting access to your account, and you agree to accept responsibility for all activities that occur under your account or password. Amazon does sell products for children, but it sells them to adults, who can purchase with a credit card or other permitted payment method. If you are under 18, you may use the Amazon Services only with involvement of a parent or guardian. Parents and guardians may create profiles for teenagers in their Amazon Household. Alcohol listings on Amazon are intended for adults. You must be at least 21 years of age to purchase alcohol, or use any site functionality related to alcohol. **Amazon reserves the right to refuse service, terminate accounts, terminate your rights to use Amazon Services, remove or edit content, or cancel orders in its sole discretion**.

I read that and understand in some interactions, they may not care about a distinct account or allow sharing; in other interactions, they may care.  That's it, that's the answer.

In the last sentence, Amazon has retained the right to refuse service and terminate accounts at it's sole discretion, so whether some case actually violates the terms of the agreement is in one sense a meaningless question: they can cut you off for any reason, you don't need to give them one.

As a matter of revenue protection and cost control, maybe they have a business process to uncover cases where more than one adult is sharing an account against the stated terms of service for those interactions where they do care (or the free Prime shipping or streaming utilization is getting out of control).  Sometimes a stadium pays someone to check the cheap ticket holders from moving into empty seats in a better section (and send them back where their license entitles them to be, or kick them out), sometimes they don't.

Comment: (1) The initial statement you bolded is uncertain (see both instances of "*may*" in that unspecific sentence) and does not outweigh the other terms that are consistent with the notion of multiple adults using the same account. (2) The matter of "sole discretion" would be null and void to the extent that policies akin to "*they can cut you off for any reason*" contravene consumer protection laws and the typical legislation against unfair practices. (3) The OP asks whether the *customer's acts* he mentions would violate the terms, which is independent of the *counterparty's sole discretion*.

Comment: As Iñaki said, the first sentence says "may," and also, I thought it was simply meaning that some actions require an account. Also as Iñaki said, their sole discretion to cancel an account is separate from the terms, and this question is about the terms. Since ToS says, "By using the Amazon Services, you agree, on behalf of yourself and all members of your household and others who use any Service under your account, to the following conditions," would you agree that you are allowed to let others share your account so long as you agree to the terms on behalf of them and resume responsibility?

Comment: @TheEditor I see the "others" text conveying that if you do share access in a way Amazon doesn't prevent, then if there is a downstream copyright violation or a dispute over some charge, the account holder agrees to be responsible.  Overall, what is the point of the question if you're not worried about being kicked out?  They tell you not to share the account (but know it's feasible and probably happens).  You can cheat your license pretty easily and probably without consequences but it's not the right thing to do and I'm not going to agree that it's the right thing to do.

Comment: To make sure I understand where you're coming from, where do they say not to share the account?

Comment: @IñakiViggers What are your thoughts about the "others" section meaning that the terms are merely accounting for if people cheat the license?

Comment: @TheEditor "*What are your thoughts about the "others" section*" Not sure if I understand the follow-up question correctly, but it would make no sense for the clause to establish that "*you agree, on behalf of [...] others who use*" and yet bar these "others" on whose behalf the account owner agreed to the terms.

Comment: @user662852 Just to make sure I understand your position, where are you seeing that the terms "tell you not to share the account"?

Comment: @user662852 Since I haven't heard back from you, I asked Amazon's customer service myself about this, and they also agreed that there's nothing in the terms prohibiting multiple adults from sharing the same Amazon account so long as you're okay with sharing the same credit cards. So Iñaki's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> If a family of more than two adults would like to share a single account instead of getting involved with Amazon Household, would they be in violation of Amazon's terms, whether in the section above or elsewhere?

Yes.

The terms are clear that each account can only be used by one person.

Comment: "Parents and guardians may create profiles for teenagers in their Amazon Household" would seem to contradict that.  There seems to be ambiguity in what is allowed to be shared.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What specifically in the terms do you see as prohibiting the use of an account by more than one person?

Comment: I just updated the question upon discovering an additional relevant quotation from the terms, which says the one agreeing does so on behalf of anyone who uses the account, not just the one agreeing. Might this affect the answer?